# Java, MySQL or PHP - rounding down minutes to the next 10 minutes

Tags: java, php, mysql, datetime, rounding

I want to round down current time in 10 minutes block. I can do so either on Java, php or mysql (preferably), whatever is considered better. For example:

`08:49:50 -> 08:40:00`

`14:23:12 -> 14:20:00`

`09:32:11 -> 09:30:00`

`12:20:00 -> 12:20:00`

I tried to solution from [Round date to 10 minutes interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192424/round-date-to-10-minutes-interval) but mysql fails with it.

Comment: Either/or can do the job. Take your pick.

Comment: The first one that will make it work - I will take it :) preferably to mysql

Comment: No wonder MySQL fails when you try to feed it Oracle procedure code. You don't copy/paste the code, you understand what it does and reproduce the same result yourself using MySQL procedure code.

Comment: At first it was a general one of syntax error, then I removed the casting to timestamp so it says trunc is not a recognized function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer from the following stackoverflow post : [How to round a time to the nearest 15 minute segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708294/how-to-round-a-time-to-the-nearest-15-minute-segment)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( TRUNCATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) / 900,0)*900);
```

Credits to Gavin Towey!

Just replace 900 (15 mins) with 600 (10 mins).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date roundDown10Min(Date date) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int roundedMinutes = (minutes/10)*10;
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, roundedMinutes );
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return cal.getTime();

}
```