# how to sum timestamps by 5 minutes

Tags: sql, analytics, exasol

I need help with taking sum of timestamps in sql by 5 mins or since I'm doing analysis so maybe i change it to 6, 7 or 10 mins , particularly in Exasol as it doesn't have all functions like datediff and dateadd.

[image: sample data]

the result should look like this :

[image: Result data]

will be helpful .

Comment: Explain how the expected result match your question. The difference is much more than 5 minutes.

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd MM:SS

Comment: Assuming that these are stored as `datetime` in MySQL, where/what are the hours for each date?

Answer (score 1):

Exasol has functions similar to `datediff` and `dateadd`: [MINUTES_BETWEEN](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/minutes_between.htm) and [ADD_MINUTES](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/add_minutes.htm)

My solution is based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192424/round-date-to-10-minutes-interval):

```
select add_minutes (
        trunc (CONTACT_DATE, 'mi'),
        mod (extract (minute from CONTACT_DATE), 5)
    ) as START_TIME
    , count (*) as CNT
from visits
group by local.START_TIME
```

Here `5` is a constant which defines length of period in minutes.